# How to determine the convergence of this series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k+1)\cdot (2k)!!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k+1)\cdot (2k)!!}.$$

Here $(2k)!!=(2k)(2k-2)\cdots 2$.

If we use Hadamard test, then the ratio is $1$.

How can we determine its convergence and find its sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note
$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2(2n+1)}}<\dfrac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots(2n-1)}{2\cdot 4\cdots (2n)}<\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$$
so
$$\dfrac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!(2n+1)}\approx \dfrac{C}{(2n+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}},n\to \infty$$
so this 
convergence

Hint 
$$\arcsin{x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\cdot\dfrac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$
let $x=1$

Comment: I do know that this equality. But when I do not know, how can I show its convergence???